# How can I set progress bar color accent programmatically?

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I'm creating ProgressDialog compatible with AppCompat. However color accent is not applied in created ProgressBar.

Link to source of my ProgressDialogCompat: 
https://github.com/krystian71115/AndroidHelperLibrary/blob/master/src/com/krystian71115/android/app/ProgressDialogCompat.java#L160

The result:

[image: ProgressDialog bug]

In that screenshot you can see the progress bar in main layout is applied correctly. But when i create this programmatically it doesn't work.

Second screenshot after close dialog:

[image: Second screenshot]

The colorAccent is working correctly but not working when i create a progress bar programmaticaly.

OnCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ProgressDialogCompat dialog = new ProgressDialogCompat(this);
    dialog.setTitle("Loading");
    dialog.setMessage("Loading data...");
    dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialogCompat.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    dialog.setProgress(150);
    dialog.setMax(300);
    dialog.show();
}
```

How can i create ProgressBar horizontal with colorAccent?

Style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
   <item name="colorAccent">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

I'm using the AppCompat.

I'm testing it on API 22 (emulator).

Comment: I have fixed it. I wrote own implementation of this. Link to source: https://github.com/krystian71115/MaterialCompat/blob/master/src/com/krystian71115/android/widget/ProgressBarCompat.java

Comment: It would be better if you post it as answer while quoting the important steps or code which does what you were looking for.